# In intern.js Leadfoot, how can I determine what device / browser I am running on?

Tags: intern, browserstack, leadfoot

I have a test suite using theintern that I run on a whole array of different browsers and devices via BrowserStack.  I would like to be able to take some slightly different actions on mobile vs desktop - is there any way I can include logic to determine what device I'm on when I'm writing my leadfoot code?

Comment: You can always use Leadfoot's 'getSessionCapabilities' command
 ('https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Server.html#getSessionCapabilities'). Or you can use your script's capability variable to get the correct platform/device/browser. Once you have that you can have if conditions in your script to achieve what you want. Can you share your use case so that someone here can provide accurate solution?

Comment: thanks @SanketParlikar how do I access the leadfoot server module?  Can I require it?

Answer (score 0):

In a functional test, you can reference information about the current session's environment via

```
this.remote.session.environment
```

You can access the session's WebDriver capabilities with

```
this.remote.session.capabilities
```